# Converting Multidimensional list into a single string in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
import sys
import math
import numpy as np

alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ "
message = "IFMMPAXPSME"
 
msg = np.array_split(list(message), len(message))
alp = np.array_split(list(alphabet), len(alphabet))
li = []


for i in range(len(msg)):
    for j in range(len(alp)):
        if msg[i] == alp[j]:
            li.append(alp[j-1:j])


print(li)
```

The result I get :

```
[[array(['H'], dtype='<U1')], [array(['E'], dtype='<U1')], 
[array(['L'], dtype='<U1')], [array(['L'], dtype='<U1')], 
[array(['O'], dtype='<U1')], [], [array(['W'], dtype='<U1')], 
[array(['O'], dtype='<U1')], [array(['R'], dtype='<U1')], 
[array(['L'], dtype='<U1')], [array(['D'], dtype='<U1')]]
```

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: @j1-lee https://www.codingame.com/training/easy/code-breaker-puzzle ,  I want to do this but with my own way

Comment: @bichanna I want to decode the message using the position of the letter in the alphabet by converting it into list and converting it back into string

Answer (score 0):

Nvm, I solved it by myself

```
import numpy as np

alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ "
message = "IFMMPAXPSME"
li = []

def Convert(string):
    list1=[]
    list1[:0]=string
    return list1

def toString(s):
    string = ""
    
    for i in s:
        string += i
        
    return string

msg = Convert(message)
alp = Convert(alphabet)



for i in range(len(msg)):
    for j in range(len(alp)): 
        if msg[i] == alp[j]:  li.append(toString(alp[j-1:j]))


print(''.join(li))
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.